# Why can't std::iter::Map<I, F> be returned as Iterator<Item = I>?

Tags: rust

I want make the mapping portion of this line into a function:

```rust
let i: Vec<u32> = (0..=5).map(|x| x * 2).collect();
```

I wrote this code which I assumed would be a drop-in for what I removed from the original code:

```rust
let j: Vec<u32> = process(0..=5).collect();
```

```rust
fn process<I>(src: I) -> I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = u32>,
{
    src.map(|x| x * 2)
}
```

I get this compile time error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:5:5
  |
1 | fn process<I>(src: I) -> I
  |            -             - expected `I` because of return type
  |            |
  |            this type parameter
...
5 |     src.map(|x| x * 2)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `I`, found struct `std::iter::Map`
  |
  = note: expected type parameter `I`
                     found struct `std::iter::Map<I, [closure@src/lib.rs:5:13: 5:22]>`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a5610a523c63493df20bbf0aaef1b58c)

Since `std::iter::Map<u32, u32>` implements the `Iterator` trait, shouldn't it be able to be returned as `Iterator<Item = u32>`?

I *was* able to get it working with [the following](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=816876fde8578efb0f1ca7e95cb78abd):

```rust
fn process<I>(src: I) -> std::iter::Map<I, Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = u32>,
{
    src.map(Box::new(|x| x * 2))
}
```

This involves wrapping the closure in a `Box`. Is there a better or less verbose way to do this that matches the inline function?

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: The caller of a generic function gets to determine what the generic type is. Your code attempts to ignore what the caller says and set a type anyway. To fix: `fn process<I>(src: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = u32> where I: Iterator<Item = u32>` or `fn process(src: impl Iterator<Item = u32>) -> impl Iterator<Item = u32>`

Comment: Looks like `impl trait` is what I was looking for based on your answer in the duplicate.
[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d40b39c80fb91e1fc574aea321008637)